# Collapsing a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to collapse a dataframe onto itself. The aggregate dataset seems like my best bet but I'm not sure how to have some columns add themselves and others remain the same.

My dataframe looks like this

```
A  1  3  2
A  2  3  4
B  1  2  4
B  4  2  2
```

How can I use the aggergate function or the ddply function to create something that looks like this:

```
A  3  3  6
B  5  2  6
```

Comment: For the third column what is the rule for aggregation?

Comment: That column I would like to keep the same. Some of the variables in my dataset are values that I would like to add while others are numeric markers that I would like to keep the same. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(col1) %>% 
   summarise_each(funs(if(n_distinct(.)==1) .[1] else sum(.)))
```

Or another option if the column 'col3' is the same would be to keep it in the `group_by` and then `summarise` others

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(col1, col3) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum))
#   col1  col3  col2  col4
#  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#1     A     3     3     6
#2     B     2     5     6
```

Or with `aggregate`

```
 aggregate(.~col1+col3, df1, FUN = sum)
 #   col1 col3 col2 col4
 #1    B    2    5    6
 #2    A    3    3    6
```

Comment: Or with `data.table` - `df1[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=.(V1,V3)]` - `df1[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=.(V1,V3)][, names(df1), with=FALSE]` if the order of the columns is important.

Comment: I'm running into a "'sum' not meaningful for factors" error. I'm assuming that means my dataframe is being created improperly and I need to convert it to something else. Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: @AlexTippett I think you may have created a matrix and then convert it to data.frame.  One way is to do `df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))` then apply the codes.